# Fisher information for marginal distribution

Tags: fisher-information

Suppose I have a random variable $X$ with the following distribution:

$$f(x|\theta)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{p(k|\theta) \cdot \varphi_k(x)},$$

where $p(k|\theta)$ is some discrete probability distribution for random variable $K$ and $\{\varphi_k(x)\}$ ($k \in \mathbb{N}$) is a set of probability distributions for random variable $X$.

I'm trying to find the Fisher information of parameter $\theta$.

Are there any helpful relations for Fisher information of parameter $\theta$ in this specific case?

Comment: You have not defined most of your notation ... which means your question should correctly be closed

Comment: @wolfies I've fixed that